# REGEX to match only entire tag containing a specific string

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

My current regex pattern:

```
(?s)]*>(.*?)\bsomethin\b(.*?)
```

HTML fragment to search:

```
<p>somethin</p>
<p>nuthin</p>
```

If I run it against the html fragment above it will match `<p>somethin</p>` which is what I need.

However, if I change the pattern embedded string from "somethin" to "nuthin" it will match both p tags in their entirety when I only want the second tag set.  The behavior is the same if I nest the p tags rather than having them on a single line and this is also desired.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you want... What do you mean with "when I only want the second tag set"? Also better use specific libraries to manipulate HTML, do not use regexes.

Comment: Welcome to why not to parse html with regex tutorial. If you skill is high enough you should write an html parser with regex yourself - from scratch. If not I would *suggest* that you use whatever utility your plattform provides for dealing with html.

Comment: I believe his issue is that if he transposes the somethin and nuthin contents, it will match from the <p> before nuthin all the way to the </p> after somethin.

Comment: Asmor is correct. My mention of nesting may have mislead - the tags are NOT nested within each other but my real (i.e., not simplified) use case has tags that run for more than one line before the closing tag.  I am attempting to capture the entire tag envelope but get two entire tags in the "nuthin" example - too greedy you know.

Answer (score 1):

Expression is quite strange and i don't exactly understand what you want. But if you wish take every tag try next regex:

```
(?s)<(.+?)>\b\w+\b</\1>
```

Accurate your question, plz.

Comment: Question is too general. No language, no details. I wrote regex for author's example. Also nothing tell could we use regex or must take another approach.

Comment: My target environment is regex find or find in files in the IntelliJ IDE.  The suggested pattern did not match anything in my code fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd recommend:

```
(<([^>\s]*)[^>]*>[*<]*somethin[*<]*</\2>)
```

This won't work if there are nested HTML tags inside your parent element, but otherwise you should be golden.

Comment: No match on either single line or multi-line tags?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select only tags with exact string use [this](https://regex101.com/r/kC5CRd/1): `<(\w+).*?>(somethin)<\/\1>`

If you want to select tag containig substring use [this](https://regex101.com/r/kC5CRd/3): `<(\w+).*?>.*?(somethin).*?<\/\1>`